# ensure user login in Ember app

Tags: ember.js

What is the best way to ensure that user is logged in into the Ember application?

I would like to intercept any URL before the routing is excited, show a modal popup with user_id/password, and go to the original URL.

Perhaps something similar to Rail's application_controller#before_filter which gets executed before any other controller methods.

I have the following routing:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('folder', {path: '/'}, function(){
        this.resource('files', {path: '/:folder_id'}, function(){
            this.route('index');
        });
    });
});
```

I am trying to setup ApplicationRoute:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    activate: function(){
        console.log("activating app route");
    }
});
```

But the problem is, if I hit `index.html#/folder01`, `folder` route is executed before the `application` route.

Summarizing the workflow ideally should look like:

1. User hits `index.html#/folder01` URL
2. App checks whether user logged in. If not modal popup appears
3. After login, the app should render `index.html#/folder01` URL

Thanks a lot!

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416143/ember-js-authentication/15429584#15429584) especialy the redirect method

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found a solution that works. Here it is:

```
App.Router.reopen({
    startRouting: function() {
        if (!App.userProfile.get('loggedIn')) {
            $("#login_dialog").modal('show').one('click', "#login_btn", function(){
                $("#login_dialog").modal('hide');
                App.userProfile.set('loggedIn', true);
                App.startRouting();
            });
        } else {
            this._super();
        }
    }
});
```

If the App detects a session timeout, it executes `window.location.reload()`. Would be nice to have `App.reset()` working but afaik it has not been implemented correctly yet.

I am not 100% sure this solution does not have problems like memory leaks or things like that. I would love to hear anything from the Ember experts about this approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use your route to accomplish this:

```
App.DatasetEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    if (this.controllerFor('currentUser').get('isSignedIn') === false) {
      this.transitionTo('user.login');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created [userapp-ember](https://github.com/userapp-io/userapp-ember) which is an Ember.js module for user authentication. It's meant for [UserApp](https://www.userapp.io/), but it's open-source, so you could modify it to use your own service instead if you'd like.

To demonstrate briefly how I solved the problem:

```
App.ProtectedRouteMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
  beforeModel: function(transition) {
    // check if the user if authenticated
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      transition.abort();
      this.transitionTo('login'); // transition to the login route
    }
  }
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.ProtectedRouteMixin);
```

I used a mixin to extend all routes that I wanted to protect. The mixin listens on the `beforeModel` event and aborts the transition if the user is not logged in (`isAuthenticated`). Then, instead of redirecting to the login route, you could show a login popup instead. After a successful login, reload the page or transition to the same route.